# Datagrid trigger Usercontrol based on value

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF Datagrid where column 2 contains certain values. I want to make it so if the user clicks any cell within row 1, and the value in (row 1, column 2) is true, a user control will pop up.

I know how to change the color of the row by using

```
                 <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding itemCtrlType}" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aqua"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

I was thinking about trying to nest an event trigger in this but I'm stumped on how to do this. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: The MVVM pattern breaks down here... Try adding a presenter to make this the MVPVM pattern. They have the presenter do the popup when it detects the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me, if I understand your question. I don't know what your boolean property is called; I wrote one called `IsOdd`.

This opens a popup on any row when:

- The row is selected, **and**
- That row's `DataContext` has an `IsOdd` property equal to `False`

The `Popup`'s `DataContext` is the row's `DataContext`. Put any XAML in there that you want to, `UserControl` or whatever.

The only thing here that really bugs me is the row presentation XAML (everything inside `SelectiveScrollingGrid`). That kind of spoils the s/n ratio in the answer, but it has to be there. At least you've got control over it.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Grid>
                        <!-- 
                        Stole content presentation from here: 
                        http://stackoverflow.com/a/14266323/424129
                        -->
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                            <DataGridCellsPresenter 
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                />
                            <DataGridDetailsPresenter 
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}" 
                                />
                            <DataGridRowHeader 
                                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical"
                                Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" 
                                />
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                        <Popup
                            x:Name="RowPopup"
                            IsOpen="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            >
                            <Border 
                                MinWidth="200" 
                                MinHeight="166" 
                                Background="WhiteSmoke"
                                BorderBrush="Black"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                Padding="12"
                                >
                                <TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Blah blah popup. " />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsOdd, StringFormat=IsOdd: {0} }" />
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Border>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <!-- 
                        The RelativeSource=TemplatedParent binding doesn't seem to be working here. 
                        I don't understand why not. Probably something stupid and obvious. 
                        -->
                        <!-- 
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition 
                                    Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                    Value="True" />
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsOdd}" Value="False" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="RowPopup" Property="IsOpen" Value="True" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        -->

                        <!-- 
                        So instead, we bind IsOpen on the popup to IsSelected, and then 
                        override that with False if the boolean property is true. Clumsy 
                        but it works. 
                        -->
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOdd}" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="RowPopup" Property="IsOpen" Value="False" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```