# DataGridTemplateColumn Column Span in DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am making UI as shown in picture below.

[image: DataGrid]
It is a DataGrid, Itemsource is bound to a List. I cannot set `ColumnSpan` for the `TextBox`. First, I tried it with a `UserControl` but I couldn't fix DataGridTemplateColumn Header, then I tried DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate but couldn't set the `ColumnSpan`.

Is there any way/method to make this kind of Datagrid?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `ColumnSpan` in the `DataGrid`, like in the normal `Grid`.

To get this kind of layout you have 3 choices, all with heavy drawbacks unfortunately.

### 1 merge cells

Use the merge event to merge cells together in code behind. [See a
    guide to this here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/620909/How-to-merge-datacells-in-WPF-DataGridView) This requires a large chunk of code behind
    coding to get this right with your layout. So I would really advise
    against this.

### 2 RowDetails

Use the build in `RowDetails`. This doesn't get the layout exactly like your's but is the easiest and closest build in function to your requirement.

It will look something like this:

[image: Row Template]

It's easy to configure:
Set: `RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible"` in the DataGrid XAML.
And define your template for the row:

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Desc}" Background="LightGray"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

`[+]` All DataGrid functions will work: Sorting, Adding Rows, Resizing ...

`[-]` The Details section span over the whole row.

See [this tutorial about what you can do with row details.](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/details-row/)

### 3 Hack something together

With templates and code behindz. Some resources that might help you:

- [Override Row Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264087/creating-a-controltemplate-for-a-datagridrow-in-wpf)
- [Build a custom cell template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celltemplate(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [DataGrid in general](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee340710(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for advice. Now, I  am going to try as you have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

DataGrid is not suitable for what you want.
You had better use ListView or ListBox and datatemplate.  By using them, you can show every kind of data in the way you want without DataGrid.

If you are not familiar with listview and datatemplete, please see the link below.
https://www.wpftutorial.net/ListBoxDataTemplate.html

Answer (score 0):

I have come with other solution using Grids, List and UserControl. In a simple way, I made it as following:
[image]

Comment: This has of course the downside, that you're missing all the DataGrid functions (Sorting, Selektion, etc etc), but easier to get the layout right.

Comment: @jHilscher Yes, you are right. All DataGrid functions are missing(no selection, no sorting,..), but selection must be implemented. :)

Comment: You can get Selektion with a listbox.